# dynamically select dataframe columns for groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe named `Incoming_Tags`
[image]

I can do `groupby` on the dataframe by mentioning the column names as input to groupby:

**Example:**

```
Incoming_Tags.groupby([ 'Domain','Tag_Name', 'Tag_hierarchy', 'html_attributes'])
```

I want to select columns dynamically for doing `groupby`.

Dynamically means by **names**. Instead of mentioning the **columns names** each time in `groupby`. I have defined a function `group_by`, which does the following:

```
def group_by(df,myList= [],*args): 
       Incoming_tag_groupby = df.groupby(myList).agg({'char_cnt': np.mean,'line_cnt':np.mean,'digit_cnt':np.mean,'sp_chr_cnt':np.mean,'word_cnt':np.mean}) 
       return Incoming_tag_groupby
```

Comment: What mean dynamically? By positions like `Incoming_Tags.groupby(Incoming_Tags.columns[:4].tolist())` ?

Comment: @Arghya, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: dynamically means by names.Instead of mentioning the columns names each time in groupby,i've defined a function group_by,which does the following :- 

def group_by(df,myList= [],*args):
     Incoming_tag_groupby = df.groupby(myList).agg({'char_cnt': np.mean,'line_cnt':np.mean,'digit_cnt':np.mean,'sp_chr_cnt':np.mean,'word_cnt':np.mean})
    return Incoming_tag_groupby

Comment: So you need `def group_by(df,myList= [],*args):
        return df.groupby(myList).mean()` ?

Comment: yes,
snippet
def group_by(df,myList= [],*args):
    if len(df.columns) == 0 or len(df.columns) == 1:
        return "groupby not possible"
    else:
        Incoming_tag_groupby = df.groupby(myList).agg({'char_cnt': np.mean,'line_cnt':np.mean,'digit_cnt':np.mean,'sp_chr_cnt':np.mean,'word_cnt':np.mean})
    return Incoming_tag_groupby
is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want aggregate all numeric columns, non numeric are excluded by [default](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns):

```
def group_by(df,myList= [],*args):
    return df.groupby(myList).mean()
```

Or with `c` list of columns for specify columns for aggregating:

```
def group_by(df,myList= [],*args): 
    c = ['char_cnt','line_cnt','digit_cnt','sp_chr_cnt', 'word_cnt']
    return df.groupby(myList)[c].mean()
```

Comment: perfect.Thank you!